# Copy two char* to **buff with memcpy - C language

Tags: c, memcpy

I got two char pointer:

```
char *a="A";
char *b="B";
```

And a pointer to pointer buffer:

```
char **buf = malloc(sizeof(char*)*2);
```

And I want use memcpy to copy two variables to buf:

```
memcpy(*buf, &a, sizeof(char*));
memcpy(*buf, &b, sizeof(char*));
```

but it replace first variable..

how can I copy two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it you actually want to do?

With

```
char **buf = malloc(sizeof(char*)*2);

memcpy(*buf, &a, sizeof(char*));
memcpy(*buf, &b, sizeof(char*));
```

unless you omitted some initialisation in between, you get undefined behaviour. The contents of the `malloc`ed memory is unspecified, so when `*buf` is interpreted as a `void*` in `memcpy`, that almost certainly doesn't yield a valid pointer, and the probability that it is a null pointer is not negligible.

If you just want `buf` to contain the two pointers, after the `malloc`

```
buf[0] = a;
buf[1] = b;
```

is the simplest and cleanest solution, but

```
memcpy(buf, &a, sizeof a);
memcpy(buf + 1, &b sizeof b);
```

would also be valid (also with `&buf[1]` instead of `buf + 1`.

If you want to concatenate the strings `a` and `b` point to, you're following a completely wrong approach. You'd need a `char*` pointing to a sufficiently large area to hold the result (including the 0-terminator) and the simplest way would be using `strcat`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your program with my own test code: I hope this helps:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 10
#define ARRAY_LENGTH 2
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *a = "A";
    char *b = "B";
    char **buf = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*ARRAY_LENGTH);
    *buf = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LENGTH);
    *(buf+1) = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LENGTH);
    memset(buf[0],0,10);
    memset(buf[1],0,10);
    memcpy(buf[0],a,strlen(a));
    memcpy(buf[1],b,strlen(b));
    printf("%s %s",buf[0],buf[1]);
    free(buf[0]);
    free(buf[1]);
        free(buf)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code wasn't indented, so some `*` were interpreted as markdown, OP wants to copy `char *`.

Comment: This is bad code: 
char **buf; *buf[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXLENGTH); *buf[1] = malloc(char)*MAXLENGTH); memcpy(&(*buf[0]),&a, strlen(a)); malloc(&(*buf[1]),&b,strlen(b));